# Method applied to a variable vs. method applied to a list

Tags: python

I am very new to Python as I started studying it a few days ago.

I am a bit confused, so please help me clarify my thoughts.

Consider the following two code snippets:

```py
name = "My name is John."
print(name)
new_name=name.upper()
print(new_name)
```

and

```py
numbers = ["A","B","C"]
print(numbers)
numbers.remove("A")
print(numbers)
```

In the first code, we define the new variable `new_name = name.upper()` which is the old variable `name` to which we applied the method `upper()`, and then I print it. However, in the second code, I don't define the new variable; instead, I apply the method `remove()` directly to the list `numbers`, and then I print it.

However, if I try to modify my first code in the following way:

```py
name = "My name is John."
print(name) 
name.upper()
print(name)
```

It won't produce the desired result. The same applies to the second code:

```py
numbers = ["A","B","C"] 
print(numbers) 
new_numbers = numbers.remove("A") 
print(new_numbers)
```

Perhaps I'm asking a simple question, but I'm quite curious about this inconsistency in the codes. Thank you

This is my second day learning how to code in Python, and I've tried to figure out my question, but I couldn't find the solution. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what the problem is.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, functions which modify their inputs return nothing, and functions which don't will return the modified result.

Comment: Some methods alter their parent object directly (such as `numbers.remove("A")` in your example), and some methods return new objects (such as `name.upper()` in your example.)  You just have to memorize which does what.

Answer (score 2):

You have discovered the concept of [immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Python).

#### Strings Are Immutable

In Python, strings cannot be changed. One can only create a new string based on an old one. For example, `name.upper()` creates a *new* string containing the same letters as the original string, but uppercase. It **does not** (and cannot) change the original `name` string.

This is why you *must* do:

```py
new_name = name.upper()
```

`new_name` is the new string that was created, and `name` is still the same original string.

#### Lists Are Mutable

It is possible to edit an existing list without creating a new list. We can add, remove, or update elements in-place (thereby modifying / mutating the list).

For example:

```
numbers.append(5)
```

This adds a new element to an existing list, without creating a new list. If you wish to create a new list (without updating the original), you can choose to make a copy first:

```py
new_numbers = numbers.copy()
new_numbers.append(5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, I am still a bit confused with your answer (especially the second part about lists). Could you please clarify how it addresses my question?

Comment: Why does the last code in my post give the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

In your first snippet of code:

```
name = "My name is John."
print(name)
new_name=name.upper()
print(new_name)
```

`name` is a variable of type `str`. It has a method called `.upper()` to return a copy of itself but with all characters capitalized. Hence, that copy is assigned to the new variable `new_name`, and `new_name` is `name` with all the characters capitalized. Note that the method `.upper()` has no side effect, meaning that the value of the variable invoking this method (`name` in this case) stays the same. It is just its returned value that we're interested in.
You can read about `str.upper()` here in Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper

In your second snippet of code:

```
numbers = ["A","B","C"]
print(numbers)
numbers.remove("A")
print(numbers)
```

The variable `numbers` is of type `list`. It has a method called `.remove()` to remove the first element in the list equal to the argument provided. This is the side effect of `.remove()`. However, it does not return anything, so it's meaningless to assign the result of `.remove()` to some variable.
Here are the methods of `list` in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

`name.upper()` does not modify the value bound to `name` at all; it returns a *new* string that gets bound to the original name.

```
>>> name = "foo"
>>> name.upper()
'FOO'
>>> name
'foo'
```

`numbers.remove("A")`, on the other hand, *does* modify the existing list bound to `numbers`, rather than create a new list that is identical to the old list sans `"A"`. It does not return the list; it simply returns `None`, so you would not want to assign `None` back to the name.

```
>>> numbers = [1,2,3]
>>> numbers.remove(1)
>>> numbers
[2, 3]
```

(When a lone value of `None` is returned, the interactive interpreter simply does not output anything.)

In general, you just need to read the documentation to see whether a method *mutates* its object, or returns a new value. As a rule of thumb, functions that you might expect to return a value but return `None` instead have mutated their object.